# R: Understanding dput() output

Tags: r, dput

I have recently learnt the command `dput()` thanks to SO users. The issue now is that I don't understand the output. I am wanting to understand the data for my variable edu.deg.level. I can see there are 10 values in a list format but I do not understand what 1L, 0L mean or what they are assigned to. Here's the code:

```
> dput(head(df1,10))
 structure(list(edu.degree.level = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 0L), immig.view = structure(c(7, 4, 5, 1, 7, 5, 7, 1, 3, 1), 
 label = "J1 Do you think immigration is good or bad for Britain's economy?", 
 labels = c(`Not stated` = -999, 
`Don`t know` = -1, `1 Bad for economy` = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, 
`4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7 Good for economy` = 7), class = "haven_labelled")), 
 row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `1L` is just the number `1`, but stored as an integer (same for `0L` etc.). It is showing the values of each of the columns of your data frame.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks. So just to confirm, if there is 1L the value in the data frame is 1 if 2L it is 2 etc?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main types "numeric" atomic vectors to think of in R. The first is "integers", or counting numbers, think of these as numbers like you would use for counting etc. -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3... The other is the "double" type or real numbers which is numbers that can be anywhere along an infinitely long number line, e.g. -8.43, -2.10, 0.001, 18.2797615.

Following the number with an `L` simply tells R they are integers not real numbers. In your dput it is simply that the column is full of 1s and 0s and that these are integers.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. Very useful!

Comment: I now understand 10 integers for the variable as 1 or 0 but I still don't understand why the list has x10 when there are only x9 for the variable immig.view. Here is the r output:                                                                                                                      Labels:
 value              label
  -999         Not stated
    -1         Don`t know
     1  1 Bad for economy
     2                  2
     3                  3
     4                  4
     5                  5
     6                  6
     7 7 Good for economy